# How to paint terrain at higher resolution without using a giant 8K texture?

Tags: materials, resolution

I can't find an answer to this question anywhere online, unfortunately.

I am trying to paint a terrain mesh I made for a game. It is an expansive, mountainous terrain.

My problem is, it is simply too big to have non-overlapping UVS on the terrain texture. What I mean is, it looks like Blender is trying to force me to fit an entire terrain texture on a single 4096 texture. This simply isn't enough space because the terrain is hundreds of units wide.

How can I set up Blender to do what Unity does, where I can upscale/tile the texture materials sizes to sizes I see fit in such a way, that Blender will not require me to fit the entire terrain texture on a single huge texture image.

(I hope this makes sense.)

Even with a 4096 texture that I am painting on, the overall resolution on the terrain is very blurry because of the HUGE size of the terrain. I need Blender to not require non-overlapping UVS for the final painted terrain texture. Does that explain it better?

Help would be much appreciated, I can't find an answer to this anywhere.

(Yes, I did check recommended searches and bookmarked the top result. Any tutorial on this or updated ways to achieve what I would like to do?)

Comment: please do not use capital letters, because the could be interpreted as rude. Thanks.

Comment: *"I need Blender to not require non-overlapping UVS for the final painted terrain texture."* ... so, you want a repeating texture? I don't understand your question. If you have a huge mesh, You can texture it with a large image to paint it without repetitions. (But you don't want this). Or use a smaller image and get repeatings (you want that?). Or you can use UDIMs which are basically several tiled images (the required disk space will be the same as for one huge image. They just don't need in the memory at the same time). Or you can tile the mesh and use several images. Smaller image =>blurry